# Tag badges are being awarded incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges, tag-score

On Stack Overflow, I have 428 [java](/questions/tagged/java) questions answered with a total score of 775 as of the writing of this post. [However, I was just awarded the Java tag badge.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/java?userid=1768232)

[image: Activity page screenshot]

It seems that this is happening to a lot more people than just me.

- [Tracked tag badge incorrectly shown as earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254396/tracked-tag-badge-incorrectly-shown-as-earned)
- [Incorrect tag badge awarded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291546/incorrect-tag-badge-awarded)
- [Profile Activity Tracker Bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254400/profile-activity-tracker-bug)
- [Can't track a tag badge in my profile](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10509/cant-track-a-tag-badge-in-my-profile) (Only possibly related)?
- [Does this gold badge belong to me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291556/does-this-gold-badge-belong-to-me)

Comment: Something is definitely bugged there. I can see two other people got it too. [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/581205/maaartinus) is at least *close*, but [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2030471/nishant-shreshth) is nowhere near. The odd thing is it's still awarding them. [This user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson) just received it for the R tag and doesn't meeting the requirements. The tag badges are normally mass-awarded at 03:00 with the tag updates and then don't get awarded at all the rest of the day. Weird, very weird.

Comment: @animuson I just noticed those other users too. Well, keep us posted :)

Comment: +1 for honesty. I think there's a fair delay with these, but in your case it doesn't look like your recent answers even going back a few days on Java would be enough to plug 225.

Comment: And apparently I just randomly received the one for the PHP tag. o.o

Comment: @James I did get about 50 votes in the last few weeks, but still a long way to go :)

Comment: Looks like a bug. Anything rolled out recently @animuson which could effect this? Someone else just reported the same issue with another badge http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254396/tracked-tag-badge-incorrectly-shown-as-earned

Comment: Oddly I had just gotten a downvote on a super old *question* of mine immediately before I got the badge. Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Another report on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291546/incorrect-tag-badge-awarded.

Comment: Also had the experience a few hours ago -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254402/197939

Comment: Now another one [Does this gold badge belong to me?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291556/does-this-gold-badge-belong-to-me)

Comment: Just got unjustified gold for PL/SQL too, in case another data point is useful. Shortly after an upvote I think, so the delay looked similar to when a 'good answer' badge is awarded.

Comment: @animuson you are of those people who are supposed to know what's happening :). Not the ones who are surprised.

Comment: It is a conspiracy. Oracle did buy SE Inc. and to increase the virtual popularity of java every user on SO gets the tag on their profile. Live with it and move on...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One should never push code right before going on vacation.

The bug has been fixed, a test has been written, and any incorrectly-awarded badges have been revoked. Your topbar's achievement list has also been cleaned.

My apologies.

Comment: https://twitter.com/iamdevloper/status/450905958139834368

Comment: I live to break rules, @Pureferret.

Comment: and just for that, I'm going to deploy even more code this Friday! :)