# Tracked tag badge incorrectly shown as earned

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

**Note**: I don't seem to have actually been awarded the badge.

I just got this message:

[image]

however, I'm still quite a bit away from the reputation requirement:

[image]

I didn't get a notification that I earned the badge, nor is it in my badge list. But I cannot select it for tracking anymore:

[image]

Not sure if this is related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253516/142802

---

I did **not** get the badge awarded, but maybe it's just not that time of the day yet (does the tracking earning notice and the actual awarding occur on different schedules)?

[image]

Comment: Seems something is wrong - see also recent http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254396/tracked-tag-badge-incorrectly-shown-as-earned

Comment: @durron597: I want to make clear that I did not get the badge awarded, but maybe both issues have the same source?

Comment: @Felix I would imagine this is the same issue, or a knock-on effect. Even if this get's closed as a dupe (which arguably it isn't) Stack will likely suss the issue. I've added a note right at the top to make it clear from the outset, as it's potentially useful info in addition to other folks actually getting badges

Comment: "Yes, same issue. The system has "determined" they should be awarded the badge and hasn't gotten around to it yet." - [animuson ♦ in Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3364229#3364229)

Comment: Just as a bit of relevant information, my bronze/silver/gold badge trackers (the other tracker) also seems to report awarding badges way ahead of when I've actually earned it despite completing the criteria, so if the batch badge awarding script isn't run yet, it's possible that the badge is coming soon. Be paitent.

Comment: @Unihedron: That would mean I must have gotten 41 upvotes for that tag within the last day or two (lets be conservative), which seems rather unlikely.

Comment: This should now be fixed.  Let me know if you still see any strange behavior with the "congrats" messages.