# Profile Activity Tracker Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-badges

logged on today and my activity tracker suddenly changed to this:

[image: 1]

but....

[image: 2]

still about 40 away from even getting awarded the grammar badge.

Don't know what the tracker is *thinking*.