# Incorrect message when earning a badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, notifications

[My profile page on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563088/erno-de-weerd) was tracking the gold badge for [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) with still 104 votes to go to earn it.

I earned a revival badge and was greeted by "Congratulations you earned the WPF badge". The profile page switched to tracking the badge for [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)

Not a big bug (I didn't get a badge I shouldn't have) but still wrong and messing up my tracking.

Comment: Something was fixed recently regarding tag badges (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254395/tag-badges-are-being-awarded-incorrectly); your issue is probably just a fallout of that.

Comment: Confirming - the linked bug report is the issue. You should see things as normal now.

Comment: @Oded - The linked bug report has been marked as status-completed. This bug has appeared on my profile page 6 hours ago. Was the fix rolled out on SO at that time?

Comment: @Erno - the fix was rolled out about 3 hours ago.

Comment: @Oded - Ah ok, thanks.