# Extra tag badges bug not completely cleaned up

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

So last night we had a problem with  [Tag badges are being awarded incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254395/tag-badges-are-being-awarded-incorrectly)

Thankfully, it's mostly fixed now. However, there's still a problem... the totals are still wrong:

[image: Totals wrong screenshot]

This issue was fixed several hours ago, and the badges were taken away, so my guess would be that this totaling problem isn't going to fix itself on its own.

For what it's worth, this isn't just me. The people mentioned in the comments on the other post also appear to be wrong: [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson?tab=badges) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581205/maaartinus?tab=badges) [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2030471/nishant-shreshth?tab=badges)

Comment: I would give it more than a few hours... That stuff tends to be heavily cached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get cleaned up around 3am UTC, give or take a few minutes.

There is a daily cleanup job that will clear these up - should run around that time (that and other jobs run in the same batch, so this can be a few minutes after 3am).