# Activity reputation pane shows a tag is completed when it's not

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges

The reputation pane in the new activity tab shows I have achieved a gold badge for the [async-await](/questions/tagged/async-await) tag:

[image]

However, my score isn't high enough and the badges section doesn't show that badge.

Comment: This is a side-effect of [this previous bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254395/tag-badges-are-being-awarded-incorrectly). You should be able to just click "Track the next one" and it will repopulate that tracker.

Comment: @animuson It does. Last time I tried it didn't let me choose that badge as it was already completed.